LSPconfig and filetypes management
I'm working on a django project.
The html django templates are recognized by neovim as htmldjango file types.
I want that my lsp server for html works also for htmldjango file types.
So i configure my html LSP server this way:
lspconfig.superhtml.setup{
    cmd = {html_path, "lsp"},
    filetypes = {"superhtml", "html", "htmldjango"},
    }

The problem is that this LSP server (superhtml) reacts this way:
[err] (super_lsp): unrecognized language id: 'htmldjango'
[err] (default): unrecognized language id, exiting

Is there a way to:

Launch the superhtml LSP server when i open a htmldjango file
Make understanding superhtml that it's just a classic html file


For now, i recommend to just change filetype systematically adding that to your init.lua:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
  pattern = "htmldjango",
  callback = function()
    vim.bo.filetype = "html"
  end,
})


You could also consider reporting to the superhtml maintainers this issue and finding out if they would consider changing the server to accept this "language ID." (You might have to patch it yourself if they don't want it, though.)
